# How to remove close button from minicart and when all product gets deleted then it should automatically close popup?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I overridden content.html file and removed below code

```
 <button type="button"
        id="btn-minicart-close"
        class="action close"
        data-action="close"
        data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko --></span>
</button>
```

Comment: usually it close when you click out of minicart , and you want it closed when you delete the last item in it.... right ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal yes I want to close when last item gets deleted